# How can I do an Ajax call in Javascript to include data plus an image file (Other Questions only relate to uploading just a file)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have code that works fine, validating some input text fields, then doing an AJAX POST to a back end PHP file to process the data.

What I now need to do is allow an uploaded image ***PLUS data fields*** to be included in the set of input fields and pass this to the server in the POST. I can add an input="file" input statement to my HTML, and can get the filename as

```
var org = document.getElementById("orgimg").value;
```

......but how do I process and include it in the POST?

I DON'T want to use jQuery - as I have a lot of vanilla JS and would like to stick with it.

A summary of the existing code is as follows; (Doesn't include all of the validation or all of the data fields).

```
function   ProcessData() {
      // Get and Validate the input fields 
      // eg var oname= document.getElementById("oname").value;
      //    etc. etc..ar http = new ajaxRequest();   
         
    var url = "example.com/processregs.php";
    var params = "s=1&oname="+oname+"&ouname="+ouname+"&opword="+opword+"&ocname="+ocname; 
    
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {                    
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {        // Response is OK       
            var ret = http.responseText;                        // Get response
            Returnreg = JSON.parse(ret);                            // Parse it
            if (Returnreg['Status'] === 9) {                        // if an error code
                orgregerr.innerHTML = Returnreg ['Error'];          // Error will be in [Error]         
            } else {
                if (Returnreg['Status'] === 8) {                        // 8 = a Database problem
                    orgregerr.innerHTML = "Server or Database Error - Reload and Try again or contact support";
                } else {
                    alert ("Data Process OK");                  
                    return;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    http.send(params);  
}
```

EDIT:: Thanks for the responses and help, I've modified code but am getting an "Undefined index: imgfile " error on the server side. If I test for oname on server that is also undefined index.

New Code is:

```
function   ProcessData() {
      // Get and Validate the input fields 
      // eg var oname= document.getElementById("oname").value;
      //    etc. etc..
    var http = new ajaxRequest();        
    var url = "example.com/processregs.php";
    var oimg = document.getElementById("orgimg").files[0];

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("imgfile",oimg);
fd.append("s","1");
fd.append("oname",oname);
fd.append("ouname",ouname);
    
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {                    
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {        // Response is OK       
            var ret = http.responseText;                        // Get response
            Returnreg = JSON.parse(ret);                            // Parse it
            if (Returnreg['Status'] === 9) {                        // if an error code
                orgregerr.innerHTML = Returnreg ['Error'];          // Error will be in [Error]         
            } else {
                if (Returnreg['Status'] === 8) {                        // 8 = a Database problem
                    orgregerr.innerHTML = "Server or Database Error - Reload and Try again or contact support";
                } else {
                    alert ("Data Process OK");                  
                    return;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    http.send(fd);  
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2508881 gives you the general idea. Basically, you need to use FormData. If you don't like that one, have a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=xhr+upload+file+and+data).

Comment: Ah ok thanks @ADyson - so I need the html inputs in a form ?  Don't have that at the moment - they are just a set of inputs with a button and onclick="ProcessdData" at the bottom.

Comment: No. You can write anything into a FormData object using code, if you want to. In fact, that's shown in that example I linked you to to - e.g. `fd.append("username", "Groucho");`.

Comment: But obviously if you wrap them in a form, it can grab all the form inputs automatically, saving you a bit of effort. More examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: @ADyson - thanks for the pointers - I've updated the code (See EDIT) - but am getting an undefined index on imgfile

Comment: You mean in PHP? Post the exact error message and the line of code it came from

Comment: first line in php file; $fileName = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];

An Error has occurred - Report the following together with what you were doing at the time:<br><br><errorentry>
 <datetime>2022-10-19 19:00:37 (BST)</datetime>
 <errornum>8</errornum>
 <errortype>Notice</errortype>
 <errormsg>Undefined index: imgfile</errormsg>
 <scriptname>/home/togdaysco/public_html/TDOrganiserRqsts.php</scriptname>
 <scriptlinenum>14</scriptlinenum>
</errorentry>

Comment: Hmm. http.setRequestHeader("Content-type needs removing, that's the wrong content type for binary uploads. Remove it and let xhr handle setting it. See if that helps

Comment: @ADyson - Bingo - Excellent, that works -  you are a star - thanks for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248915/discussion-between-phil-jones-and-adyson).